# Why Bootstrap code to create three columns is not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am beginner in web application development and I am trying to use Bootstrap framework to create a webpage. Within my meteor test project, I have two templates. One is navTest.html and other is columnTest.html. Both the templates uses bootstrap classes to style the elements. However, columnTest template is not creating 3 equal width columns for which I have written the code. Where as the navTest template is working properly as it is creating a navigation bar using the bootstrap classes. My question is why bootstrap code is working in one template but not in other. It appears that I am doing something wrong for which I am looking for help. To add bootstrap package, I have used the following command:

```
meteor add bootstrap
```

Here's the code for columnTest.html

```
<template name="columnTest">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Column 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Column 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Column 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's the code for navTest.html

```
<template name="navTest">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Here's the code for html file from where I am using these templates:

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
```

```
<div class="container">
    {{> columnTest}}
</div>
<div class="container">
    {{> navTest}}  
</div>
</body>
```

Here's how resulting webpage looks:
[image]

Comment: The class `col-4` is wrong, it should be something like `col-xs-4`

Comment: I used col-sm-4 also inplace of col-4, still no change in result.

Comment: Do not add the `bootstrap` package, it's going to add Bootstrap 2, instead use `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` to get the latest Bootstrap 3.

Comment: After I replaced the bootstrap package with twbs:bootstrap, the problem i was facing got resolved. Thank you @saimeunt for your help.